# why my crontab doest run my telegram bot php code in server?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

i have a php code for my telegram bot. when i run

```
php mybot1.php
```

this is work.
i put it to crontab table:

```
38 11 * * *  php /var/mybot1.php
```

then i restart cron service:

```
/etc/init.d/cron  restart reload
```

and i wait to run.
i dont see any thing in bot.
this is my     cron status :

```
cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cron.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2019-01-30 11:37:09 +0330; 57s ago
     Docs: man:cron(8)
 Main PID: 22986 (cron)
    Tasks: 5
   Memory: 56.2M
       CPU: 85ms
   CGroup: /system.slice/cron.service
           ├─14795 /bin/bash /var/www/new/ehcp/ehcpdaemon2.sh
           ├─14941 php index.php daemon
           ├─15031 sudo -u vsftpd /var/www/new/ehcp/ftp_server2.py
           ├─15034 /usr/bin/python -u /var/www/new/ehcp/ftp_server2.py
           └─22986 /usr/sbin/cron -f

Jan 30 11:37:09 ns1 systemd[1]: Started Regular background program processing daemon.
Jan 30 11:37:09 ns1 cron[22986]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
Jan 30 11:37:09 ns1 cron[22986]: (CRON) INFO (Skipping @reboot jobs -- not system startup)
Jan 30 11:38:01 ns1 CRON[23378]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Jan 30 11:38:01 ns1 CRON[23379]: (root) CMD (php /var/mybot1.php)
Jan 30 11:38:01 ns1 CRON[23378]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

my bot job is sending an image from Img directory every day.
thanks for help.

Comment: Go check for PHP errors in the log file.

Comment: You should always specify absolute pathnames in CRON - for security reasons it truncates the environment variable HOME, so use `/usr/bin/php`